# Cannot install ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, failed-installation

I tried installing MVC 3 from the download in http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 - both with and without the Web Platform Installer. As soon as the download is finished, the installer says installation is finished, yet I get no observable effect - I can't create MVC projects and it doesn't appear in Uninstall Programs.

Any idea how I can get MVC 3 to install?

Edit: Forgot to mention, I have the just-released SP1 installed.

Comment: Does it appear in VS2010 in the new web project dialog (ensure you are targeting .NET 4.0 or it won't show up)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's as if it's not instlled.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the eventlog to see if there any errors related to Windows Installer.

We had a similar issue,  because we had the SP1 beta installed.  Uninstalling the beta, and then running the installer worked for us.